# sqrt question drawing a vector

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone explain why this doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{tikz}   
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(-1,sqrt(3));
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks,

David

Comment: ... because you need to add braces: `\draw (0,0)--(-1,{sqrt(3)});`... otherwise the parser does not disentangle the brackets belonging to the mathematical expression and the coordinates, respectively.

Comment: @marmot Perfect! That really helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code does not works is you must write sqrt(3) inside braces.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{tikz}   
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(-1,{sqrt(3)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result is

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works.